# how do we incorporate fiter logic into Vf page search

Tags: apex

i am developing a search functionality in Vf page. I have a 5 filters on the search.

I need to be able to allow filter logic like in reports

```
(1 AND 2) OR 3
```

i am not sure of the logic i need to use to build the query. If i accept the filter logic in a variable and have this on my controller. How do i parse this string and build the query

for eg

filter 1 = industry equals 'Agriculture'

filter 2 = regions equals 'Asia'

filter 3 = partner equals true

and filter logic = (1 AND 2) OR 3

how do i parse this filter logic  and build the query accordingly

Comment: Are you developing a SOQL search?

Comment: yes a SOQL search

Comment: Based on user input but with your own filters?

Comment: idea is to allow user to choose the logic, if he wants to use and or between the filters. The user chooses the logic he would enter (1 AND 2) OR 3

Comment: Dou you want to allow unlimited or limited number of combinations?

Comment: i would love to ... :) . Filters should need to work like in reports but i have a fixed no of filters which is 5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I imagine it like this. You define your logic tests as strings, put them in a map in the controller and create a parser function.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class test1 {

    public String userLogic { get; set; }
    public String output { get; set; }
    public String filter1 { get; set; }
    public String filter2 { get; set; }
    public String filter3 { get; set; }
    Map<Integer, String> filterMap = new Map<Integer, String>();

    public void createLogic(){

        filter1 = 'Industry__c = \'Agriculture\'';
        filter2 = 'Region_c = \'Asia\'';
        filter3 = 'Partner__c = true';

        filterMap.put(1, filter1);
        filterMap.put(2, filter2);
        filterMap.put(3, filter3);
    }

    public PageReference parseLogic(){

        if(String.isNotBlank(userLogic)){
            String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM MyObject__c ';    
            output = userLogic;
            for(Integer i = 1; i <= filterMap.size(); i++){
                if(output.contains(String.valueOf(i))){
                    output = output.replace(String.valueOf(i),filterMap.get(i));
                }
            }
            query += ' WHERE (' + output + ') ';
            query += ' LIMIT 100';

            output = query;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public test1(){
        createLogic();
    }
}
```

Page:

```
    1. <apex:outputText value="{!filter1}" /> <br/>
    2. <apex:outputText value="{!filter2}" /> <br/>
    3. <apex:outputText value="{!filter3}" /> <br/><br/>

    Enter your logic: 
    <apex:inputText value="{!userLogic}"/>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!parseLogic}" value="Parse" reRender="outputString"/>

    <br/><br/>

    Output: <apex:outputText value="{!output}" id="outputString" style="font-weight:bold;"/>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! Thats a neat piece of code...

Comment: Good piece of code, good job.

Comment: It is a very helpful code. But what would you do to ensure the userlogic inputted is in correct format.

Comment: But what if the filters cannot be hardcoded in the code and have to be taken from the condition object? how do we do that?